# Stack Overflow lost its padding on the sides

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, design, ios

I noticed now that Stack Overflow has its padding set to `0`, unlike before.

Note the padding on left side of the page; it looks shifted to the left and everything is touching the left-hand side of the screen.

> <strike>**Edit**: Back to normal on mobile (*iPhone 4 v6.1.3 / Safari*).</strike>
>
> **Edit**: Same problem on mobile **full site version**, mobile version is fine  (*iPhone 5 v6.1.4 / Safari*).

[image: Exmaple]

Comment: I noticed this on the iPhone about yesterday as well. It's most apparent on user profiles.

Comment: Note that I can reproduce this here on Meta, which similarly has the padding of 0.

Comment: Yup, on iPhone as well. But desktop (chrome) it's fine.

Comment: @animuson: On an iPad too? How much padding did it have before?

Comment: @minitechη: All devices. This is the main site, and uses the same CSS for everything. You can use your web browser on a desktop to reproduce this - just make the window really small. It's not a mobile bug. :)

Comment: @animuson: Oh. I thought that was the way it always was…

Comment: This problem is in desktop browsers too. resize your window width to 977px or less. (there will be a scrollbar, but there is no padding at the left...)

Comment: @bwoebi true, but this problem is recent.

Comment: That's what happens when the Stack Exchange team starts exercising regularly and eating more healthily. :D

Comment: This is a preference, not a bug. It uses the full width of a narrow window. Where's the issue? It's just not broken. It might not be very pretty, but it's not a bug.

Comment: @AndrewC it never been like this before, it happened recently.

Answer (score 5):

Hey Omar I heard you like padding so I made you a SO padding bookmarklet.

Just drag it the code to your favorites bookmark bar and click  when ever you feel the need for padding!

```
javascript:(function(){var body=document.getElementsByTagName('body');body[0].style['padding']="0 1em";})()
```

You can later change bookmark name. SO prevents JS links.

Comment: This is a _hack_, and a _hack_ is never a solution :) This problem doesn't affect me only, it affects all visitors/users.

Comment: All users can enjoy my so called hack.

Answer (score 1):

The `padding` is set to `0`, probably to make mobile interface easier to interact with.

Mobile users, particularly those with touch devices benefit heavly from larger `font size`, buttons, etc and one way to achieve that is setting `padding` to `0`

Comment: It was working fine before, it looks different now. Thanks for your input.

Comment: How does zero padding lead to a bigger font size?

Comment: if you have less spacing then you can use more space with text. it's simple logic...

Comment: But it makes the mobile interface more *difficult* to interact with, as important UI elements move towards the edge of the screen where they are more difficult to tap. This looks like a bug.