# Can the same answer get a bounty twice?

Tags: support, bounties

I answered this question [stackoverflow lost its padding on the sides](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184977/stack-overflow-lost-its-padding-on-the-sides/185327#185327) and noticed the user has set a bounty once again.
If no better answer is presented can I get a bounty twice? Is there a difference between the user awarding a bounty to an answer that already received one, and the auto-awarding of the bounty?

## oh and kittens

[image: credit to reddit/aww]

[credit](http://www.reddit.com/r/aww/comments/1hikp1/this_will_solve_all_your_problems/)

Comment: Also; little tiger!

Comment: It's not a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78187/can-bounties-be-awarded-multiple-times-by-the-same-person-on-the-same-question. That question deals only with **different** answers on the same question.

Comment: don't be greedy, you got +85 on that answer ;)

Comment: @Omar Have you seen the kitten picture in the question?

Comment: Yeah, that killing look won't change my mind! btw, I'm allergic to cats.

Comment: Stay away from the internetz ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answer that already won one bounty won't be eligible for automatic award of second bounty. Taken from the [faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/152859):

> **What is automatic awarding?**
>
> Approximately 24 hours after the end of the bounty period, if the
>   bounty starter has not manually awarded the bounty, the bounty may be
>   awarded automatically.
>
> ...
>
> 1. **The answer must have been given after the bounty was started**
> 2. The answer must have a score of at least +2
> 3. The answer must not have been written by the bounty starter

So the only option is if the user starting the bounty is manually awarding the bounty to such an answer, and this is possible indeed. See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169551/152859) as a proof: it was awarded two bounties as can be seen in the bounty score tooltip:

> [image]